NGINX reverse proxy on containerized web-app
I am trying to reverse proxy several services on a remote server that has only port 443 opened. When I route the request to services without UI, it works. But if I try to bound a route with UI it stucks in charging because is not able to find .css or .js files of the web app. This is my config:
server {
    listen 443 ;
    server_name **NAME_HOST**;

    location /nginxui/ {
        rewrite ^/nginxui(.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81/login;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /ui/login {
        rewrite ^/ui(.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/ui/login;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }


For instance, when I send a request to /nginxui (that is the dockerized version of develop.nginxproxymanager.com I get an error below
GET **NAME_HOST**/css/main.css?v=2.11.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).
Regarding the other app I get a similar error, i.e., "GET NAME_HOST/ui/static/css/main.8e11c20e.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"
How to fix my nginx.conf to redirect the request correctly and finding resources?

Basically 404 means page or file is not found. Where's your Dockerfile or compose file and main code such config files, and app that can be shared?

The idea is to make the service able to automatically redirect the static resource as it is in local. I mean I don't understand why if I run it in local is everything perfect, but if I launch it behind a reverse-proxy he stop to work.I want to understand in general how to deal with these issues.
